# Invoke a function concurrently with http server

Tags: go

I have an http server as well a channel that I range through and invoke a function `functionA()` if the channel isn't empty. Within the `mainHandler()` are some operations (not shown) that send values into the channel.

**My goal:**

Whenever something is sent to the channel I would like `functionA()` to be invoked and run concurrently with `mainHandler()`, but it appears that they are operating one at a time. I have to wait for `functionA()` to finish before `mainHandler()` can serve another request.

Any help on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan string)

    go func() {
        for s := range c {
            functionA(s)
        }
    }()

    http.HandleFunc("/", mainHandler(c))
    http.ListenAndServe(":9000", context.ClearHandler(http.DefaultServeMux))
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Although I would like `functionA()` to run concurrently with `mainHandler()`, each invocation of `functionA()` must be synchronous with respect to other invocations of itself. In other words, only one instance of `functionA()` is allowed to run at any time.

Comment: The channel `c` is [unbuffered](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2).  Communication on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until a sender and a receiver are ready.  If `mainHandler` always sends a single value to `c`, the the two goroutines synchronize on the channel operation.  Changing `c` to a [buffered](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/3) channel might fix the issue, but it's difficult to know without more info.

Comment: `FunctionA()` does run concurrently with `mainHandler()`, but the goroutines synchronize on the channel operation.  Changing to a buffered channel (`c := make(chan string, N)` where N is a number greater than zero) may help your scenario.

Comment: @MuffinTop thank you, you were right about making the channel buffered. Once I added a buffer it behaved exactly as intended. HOWEVER, is there an alternative method that'll allow me to keep it unbuffered (the buffer size is indeterminate, and just picking a really large N doesn't seem elegant)

Comment: If the average request rate for `mainHandler` is greater than the average rate of `functionA`, then the application must apply back pressure on the clients to prevent the server from consuming memory without bound. A channel with fixed capacity applies back pressure. A capacity greater than zero allows `mainHandler` to burst ahead and then wait for `functionA` to catch up. I know it's inelegant, but I have successfully fixed server response time issues by changing the capacity of a channel from zero to 20.

Comment: @MuffinTop excellent response, thank you for the wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written, once `functionA` starts running nothing will be reading from the channel `c` until `functionA` returns, so even though `functionA` runs concurrently with the goroutine that wrote to `c`, other goroutines will wait to write to `c`.

You can do this:

```
go func() {
        for s := range c {
            s:=s 
            go functionA(s)
        }
    }()
```

This will start each instance of `functionA` in a separate goroutine.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. Please see Edit 1 for the reason why.

Comment: Based on your edit, what you did was correct. Multiple instances of `mainHandler` goroutines will invoke `functionA` serially in your original implementation. `functionA` will run concurrently with the `mainHandler` instance that wrote to the channel.